# Is it possible to use "submenu" command in grub2 embedded config?

Tags: configuration, grub2

I want to enumerate all partitions of my hard drive, and include /boot/grub/grub.cfg file from each partition as a submenu. And I want to do this in embedded config file. This way all partitions will be equal.

Is it possible to use "submenu" command in  grub2 embedded config? If no, why no?

Comment: You mean have one GRUB that only shows a menu of all the other GRUB's .cfg files to pick from? Like boot to main GRUB, then pick a 2nd GRUB to run?

Comment: yes. Grub can be embedded into reserved area in the start of disk, and a want to eliminate special /boot partition. All other linuxes will contain their /boot directory on their partitions.